# Cannot enable JMS types in OracleXE 11g - component 'CONSTRUCT' must be declared

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe

We have a set of automated tests for an Oracle database that we run on a CI server using OracleXE.  Some of the tests use the AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE type like so:

```
msg SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE;
BEGIN
    msg := SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE.construct;
    msg.set_text(pMessage);
```

In the past we have used OracleXE 10g, but I am trying to upgrade to XE 11g to match the normal Oracle servers this database runs on.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to enable those types in OracleXE 11g.  I get the following errors trying to compile those packages using it:

```
1797/5   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
1797/37  PLS-00302: component 'CONSTRUCT' must be declared
1798/5   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
1798/9   PLS-00302: component 'SET_TEXT' must be declared
1799/5   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

OracleXE did not have these types installed by default in 10g either, which we remedied by executing this script found in the install:

```
RDBMS\ADMIN\prvtaqal.plb
```

Even after running that in OracleXE 11g though, the types still cannot be resolved.  I also searched the contents of other files in the same location related to JMS and found these two:

```
RDBMS\ADMIN\dbmsaqad.sql
RDBMS\ADMIN\prvtaqji.plb
```

Installing those also had no effect.

Has anyone been able to use the AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE type in OracleXE 11g and know how to work around this?  Or was the ability to work around it in XE10g a hole that they have now plugged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get around this problem.  I copied the prvtaqal.plb script from an old OracleXE 10g install over and ran that in the OracleXE 11g instance.  Types are available and all is good.

Comment: Hello ioscode, is this still the best and only way to get JMS working in Oracle 11g XE?

Comment: As far as I know, I have not looked into it since.